# Error when using XML form with Form-based GL Application template

Tags: tizen

I created a test app using the template OpenGL Application -> Form-based provided by the Tizen SDK.

The template created includes the XML form "res/screen-size-normal/IDF_FORM.xml", but it isn't used by the default template. So I changed the code in `Initialize()` to use it as follows:

```
bool
FormBasedGLForm::Initialize(void)
{
    //Construct(FORM_STYLE_NORMAL);
    result r = Construct(L"IDF_FORM");
    [...]
}
```

Where the line commented out is the original line of code used and the second line is the modified code trying to create the form based on the XML resource.

However, `Construct(L"IDF_FORM")` returns error `E_FILE_NOT_FOUND`.

Any idea what might be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need change the value of UiScalability from "Physical" to "Logical" in manifest.xml